# Foreign key column is not created (i am using has_one :details in user model and belongs_to :user in details model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
class Details < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :details
end
```

Im expecting user_id as foreign key column in details table but not created ,any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key is always on the table / model of the `belongs_to` association. You'll need to add the foreign key column manually by creating a migration.

```
$ rails g migration add_user_id_to_details user:references
```

It will result in a migration like this:

```
class AddUserIdToDetais < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :details, :user
  end
end
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
class AddUserIdToDetais < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :details, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Depending on your queries you should consider adding an index (the references migration should suggest that automatically) to improve query performance.

**Update: Working with the association**

When everything is properly set up, you can create a details record through the user record to have the `user_id` set automatically.

```
user = User.first
user.create_details(name: 'blub') # the create_association method is generated for a has_one association
```

See all methods that the [`has_one` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference) creates in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference) or the [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one).

Comment: I tried this but getting "user_id: nil" in Details table. my migration file looks like this                                  class AddUserIdToDetails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :details, :user_id, :integer

  end
end

Comment: I've added an update on working with a `has_one` association. Does that help with setting the `user_id` automatically?

Comment: Hi, by making your changes i got column called "user_id" in Details table but value is nil. My doubt is even i have to enter "user_id" value manually?. it won't pick from user table which stores login information.(devise user table)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create it by yourself, rails do not do that automatically. Try running a migration like this:-

```
class AddUserIdToDetais < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :details, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```